# Hover over image to reveal icon? Using opacity

Tags: jquery, image

I'm looking for a good tutorial on this effect: http://chrismahon.com/themes/wook/portfolio/

When you hover over a portfolio image, the opacity changes and a icon is revealed.

If anyone could help that would be great, as I dont really want to steal the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the code: That is most likely not (CSS) opacity, put just alpha transparent PNGs. I'd do something like this:

HTML

```
<a href="link">
<img src="thumbnail.gif">
<span><img src="hover-icon.png"></span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

a span {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

a:hover span {
   display: block;
}
```

Variation with opacity transition (for current browsers):

```
a span {
    transition: opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    opacity: 0;

    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

a:hover span {
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't get that nice fade with pure CSS, though.

Comment: Actually you can - in current browsers. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

i extend the rotora answer

```
.imageLink {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}

.imageLink .zoomIcon {
   display: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

$(".imageLink").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".zoomIcon").fadeIn();
},function(){
    $(this).children(".zoomIcon").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I succeed in using the css code! Great responses!